# PowerShell: send console output to file without deafening this console output

Tags: powershell, redirect, console

I have a lot of PowerShell script. One main, that calls other, child ones. Those PS scripts in their turn call windows CMD scripts, bash scripts and console applications. All these scripts and applications write messages to console. PowerShell scripts, for example, are using `Write-Host` scriptlet for this purpose.

**Question:** how can I easely redirect (send) all this console output to some file, while not deafening (canceling) this console output? I want to be able to see whats going on from console output and also have history of messages in log file.

Thanks.

Comment: Why on earth would you use `Write-Host` if you intend to do something with the output. `Write-Host` does exactly that – write something on the host. It's out of control of your script after that. You could, however, implement your own host, but I guess that's less fun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try `Start-Transcript` and `Stop-Transcript`.  It has a couple of limitations like not capturing native exe output.  It is also global to PowerShell session.

Comment: Looks like a combination of `Start-Transcript` and `Tee-Object` can grab all the output, but, unfortunately, to different files. No easy way to merge them

Comment: I also voted up for Diadistis' answer (Tee-Object), but decided to accept Keith's answer. Actually, final solution consists of hybrid of two answers, as I've mentioned in previous comment. Two separate files isn't actually a big issue for my case.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `tee` equivalent of PowerShell : [Tee-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177014.aspx)

*PS: serverfault.com and/or superuser.com are more suitable for a question like this.*

Comment: I tried Tee-Object earlier, but it does not do what I expect. It only saves to file those output that is being written with `Write-Output` (to stdout) but not with `Write-Host`. I cannot replace all `Write-Host` to `Write-Output` in PS scripts. Also, Tee-Object ignores errors output (stderr). I need **all** output that I see on console to be redirected to file. And, ideally, without capital scripts logic rewritting

Answer (score 2):

I've found script for grabbing console output: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/e8fbffde-7d95-42d9-81de-5eb3d9c089e0. Script returns HTML to preserve colors.

The only big downside - you must call it at the end of your script to capture all console output it have made.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably need to write a custom host to do this.  It's not a terribly hard thing to do, but it's does require some managed code.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. But such solution is not appropriate for my case.